# Undefined property: Cartalyst\Stripe\Stripe::$subscriptions

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

i want to create subscription for my customer i am able to create customer but when i try to create subscription it show me the error

`Undefined property: Cartalyst\Stripe\Stripe::$subscriptions`

following is my code to create subscription

```
public function createStripeSubscription($customerId,$curPackage,$type,$stripe){
      $response = $stripe->subscriptions->create([
        'customer' =>$customerId,
        'items' => [
          ['price' => $curPackage->getPriceId($type)],
        ],
      ]);
      dd($response);
}
```

I am using latest version of stripe sdk,please help i am stuck with this.

Comment: It's probably that you need to iterate with foreach. Judging on your code i think the problem consists here `['price' => $curPackage->getPriceId($type)]`. Try to dd that inside and look if it's the same error message

Comment: @w
thanks for suggestion i was doing wrong in my get priceId i was createing new instance of stripe which causeing the error but after correcting it ,now it says undegined object
Undefined property: Cartalyst\Stripe\Stripe::$products

Comment: can you update the code please

Answer (score 0):

Add line in file :

> @property \Stripe\Service\SubscriptionService $subscriptions

vendor\stripe\stripe-php\lib\StripeClient.php

OR

```
update composer
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).